# javascript: convert binary string to UInt32 big-endian without use of bitwise operations

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm writing on a shared codebase, and we have a linting rule for 'no bitwise operations'. However I'm using a short utility function for converting a binary string to an unsigned int 32, big-endian. It works well:

```
// converts a four-character string into a big endian 32-bit unsigned integer
stringAsUInt32BE(binString) {
  return (binString.charCodeAt(0) << 24) + (binString.charCodeAt(1) << 16) +
    (binString.charCodeAt(2) << 8) + binString.charCodeAt(3);
};
```

How can I do this without bitwise operations? Thanks!

Comment: You really should disable such a nonsensical linting rule for that particular function.

Comment: I assume your function has a bug for input strings whose first character is > `\x7F`. If you consider that as the desired behavior, please let us know. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/37705109/1647737

Comment: @Bergi Shows us how such rules can have *some* merit after all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace `<< x` with `* Math.pow(2, x)`.

The main difference between these two statements is the behavior for very big or negative input `x`, e.g. bitwise operators turn their operands into two-complement numbers while the other arithmetic operators don't.

```js
// converts a four-character string into a big endian 32-bit unsigned integer
function stringAsUInt32BE(binString) {
  return binString.charCodeAt(0) * 16777216 + binString.charCodeAt(1) * 65536 + binString.charCodeAt(2) * 256 + binString.charCodeAt(3);
}

console.log(stringAsUInt32BE('\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF')); // 4294967295
console.log(stringAsUInt32BE('\x00\x00\x00\x00')); // 0
```

Note the behavior for `stringAsUInt32BE('\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF')`: Your original function would return `-1` which I consider a bug. This is because `'\xFF'.charCodeAt(0) << 24 === 255 << 24` exceeds the maximum range `Math.pow(2, 32-1)-1` of a two-complement and thus overflows to `-16777216`. The function given here does not suffer from that conversion issue.

Comment: It was not intentional that a string with a first character of > `\x7F` would result in `-1`. Thanks for the insight!

Answer (score 2):

You could use an [ArrayBuffer](http://www.javascripture.com/ArrayBuffer) with 2 different views. Write the bytes in using a `Uint8Array` and read out a value using a `DataView` specifying big-endianness like this:

```
stringAsUInt32BE(binString) {
    var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(4);
    var uint8View = new Uint8Array(buffer);
    uint8View[0] = binString.charCodeAt(0);
    uint8View[1] = binString.charCodeAt(1);
    uint8View[2] = binString.charCodeAt(2);
    uint8View[3] = binString.charCodeAt(3);
    return new DataView(buffer).getUint32(0, false); // false for big endian
}
```

Using bit-manipulation will work better on older browsers when typed arrays aren't supported.